# AccessControlException on ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" "read") from DGCClient.java

Tags: java, ssl, permissions, rmi, truststore

Thank you if you can point me to a resolution.  I am using JRE 8.

After the server and client have successfully performed handshake and connection, and while no I/O stream is present, an exception occurs from the line where trustStore is set in System property below:

```
    public class CustomClientSocketFactory implements RMIClientSocketFactory, Serializable {
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        
        SSLSocket socket = null;
        try {
            File tsFile = new File("truststore.pfx");
            
            FileInputStream is = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<FileInputStream>() {
                @Override
                public FileInputStream run() {
                    FileInputStream fs = null;
                    try {
                        fs = new FileInputStream(tsFile);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("Expected file unfound: " + truststore + "; " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return fs;
                }
                
            });
            
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ks.load(is, phrase.toCharArray());
            
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(ks);
            
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
            
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.pfx");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", phrase);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "PKCS12");
                        
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
            socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"});
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new IOException(t.getMessage(), t);
        }
        
        return socket;
    }
    }
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:886)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:733)
    ...
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl_Stub.clean(DGCImpl_Stub.java:74)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry.makeCleanCalls(DGCClient.java:700)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry.access$1700(DGCClient.java:192)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread$1.run(DGCClient.java:610)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread$1.run(DGCClient.java:603)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread.run(DGCClient.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

What am I missing?  Thank you again.

The caller (from a window service using JavaService exe) has Security Manager set as well as pointing to a policy file containing these settings:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;         
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-","connect,accept";         
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "javax.net.ssl.trustStore","read";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!  I need to sign the jar files to enable the JVM to access the property values.